# SwiftUI Text hight expend top and down. How do I expend only bottom

Tags: swiftui

`import SwiftUI

struct Test2: View {

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.green)
            .frame(height:200)
            .offset(y: 100)

    VStack{
        Image("star2")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
        Text("So even if the text is suepr long, text height expend to bottom. not top and bottom")
            .font(.system(size: 30))
        .frame(width:300)
        .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

}`[image]
[[image]
[image]
When the text is too long, SwiftUI Text() height changes. But it increases toward top and bottom.
it pushes out my other views.
How can I change Text() to increase height only to down side??

Comment: Can you provide your code pls

Comment: I edited this question. I added my code. It is just a simple view with Text and Image. Since I don't want to move the star to upside. and expend text to downside..

Answer (score 2):

fix the space above the star!

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var flag = false
    let text = ["Hello World", """
So even if the text is suepr long, text height expend to bottom. not top and bottom
"""]
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.green)
                    .frame(height:200)
                    .offset(y: 100)

                VStack{
                    Color.clear.frame(height: proxy.size.height / 3)
                    Image(systemName: "star")
                    .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50).onTapGesture {
                            self.flag.toggle()
                    }
                    Text(self.text[self.flag ? 0 : 1])
                        .font(.system(size: 30))
                        .padding()
                    Spacer()
                    //Color.yellow
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image]